# How to combine Google Docs documents without previous versions changing style

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using a script (below) to combine several Google documents into one, and it mostly works, but the output document is introducing different styling (font, line-spacing) in various places – I think wherever the source documents have edits in the version history. It will do this mid-word, even, if that's where the edit was made, or for entire sections that have been added in since the original version.

Is there a way to just pull the current version, with none of the historical changes, and keep the styling intact? I've read the documentation but can't find anything about the document version information. Thank you

```
function mergeGoogleDocs() {
  var folderToMergeId = 'XXX'
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(XXX); // output doc
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderToMergeId);
  var docsToMerge = [];
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    docsToMerge.push([file.getId(), file.getName()]);
  }
  
// Clear the output document and add in the files to merge
  baseDoc.getBody().clear();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < docsToMerge.length; i++ ) {
      
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docsToMerge[i][0]).getBody();       
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();

    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        baseDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        baseDoc.getBody().appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        baseDoc.getBody().appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("Unknown element type: "+type);
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Try setting attributes within the final loop.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks - that works for some styles that don't change but some styles in the original documents vary, so I can't fully restore them like this in the loop.